# How to write text on top of a colored canvas (new to javascript)

Tags: javascript

Need to put text on top of this canvas. I'm sure this has been asked before but I need some help. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="720"
</canvas>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fillRect(1,1,2000,2000);
</script>

<script>
car canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d");
ctx.font = "60px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Text here",200,200);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 typos:

`car` instead of `var`

And `getcontext` instead of `getContext`.

You also need to set `fillStyle`, with another color than the background:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 2000, 2000);


ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);

ctx.font = "30px Verdana";
ctx.fillText("Big smile!", 10, 90);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="720">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much randy you've been a big help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a different color to make it visible on your background.

For example, add `ctx.fillStyle="white";` before you write the text but after you fill the background.

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeeto2wn/)

Comment: Instead of fiddle's please create snippets on *this* site using the snippets button. Also, if he would implement your line, he would still have the errors in the script so it wouldn't run.

Comment: Thank you for your input too!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>

   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3 ;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

   <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 2000, 2000);

       ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("Hello World", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should provide what exactly was wrong or needed to be changed, just dump a bit of code is not an answer.